# Show the first string from a list of strings that appears in a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe of colours `df` and a list of reference colours `look_for`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['Black12', 'White', 'WhiteBlack', 'RedWhite', 'RedGreen', 'Yellow']})
look_for = ['White', 'Black', 'Red', 'Green']
```

I am trying to create a column `colour2` such that it represents the first word from `look_for` that appears in the string of each row. What is a time efficient way to accomplish this since my data frame has 2M+ colour entries and my reference list has 500+ colour entries.

My desired output is:

```
Out[0]: 
       colour colour2
0     Black12   Black
1       White   White
2  WhiteBlack   White
3    RedWhite   White
4    RedGreen     Red
5      Yellow    None
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `apply` and a custom function where you check for each item in the list, if it's substring of the given string value, return the value immediately, it will be reasonably fast.

```py
def getString(value):
    for item in look_for:
        if item in value:
            return item

df['colour2'] = df['colour'].apply(getString)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
       colour color2
0     Black12  Black
1       White  White
2  WhiteBlack  White
3    RedWhite  White
4    RedGreen    Red
5      Yellow   None
```

A quick speed comparison:

```py
Iteration:  0
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.extract: 0.00060 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.findall: 0.00296 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with custom function and apply: 0.00046 seconds
---------------------
Iteration:  1
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.extract: 0.00055 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.findall: 0.00272 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with custom function and apply: 0.00051 seconds
---------------------
Iteration:  2
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.extract: 0.00056 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.findall: 0.00265 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with custom function and apply: 0.00056 seconds
---------------------
Iteration:  3
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.extract: 0.00069 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.findall: 0.00269 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with custom function and apply: 0.00045 seconds
---------------------
Iteration:  4
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.extract: 0.00053 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with str.findall: 0.00265 seconds
Avergae time for 1000 iteration with custom function and apply: 0.00051 seconds
---------------------
```