# Pandas: Adding suffix to column names programmatically while dropping out common columns after concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes where several columns are same. I want to make some of them unique. And remaining of them should be dropped.

```
df1.columns = ['payeeId', 'name','amount','Category','Rule_No','Short Rule Name','Incident','Flag_Type']
df2.columns = ['payeeId', 'name','amount','Category','Rule_No','Short Rule Name','Incident','Flag_Type']
df3.columns = ['payeeId', 'name','amount','Category','Rule_No','Short Rule Name','Incident','Flag_Type']
df4.columns = ['payeeId', 'name','amount','Category','Rule_No','Short Rule Name','Incident','Flag_Type']
```

Now I want `Short Rule Name`, `Incident`, `Rule_No` and `Flag_Type` to be renamed with a suffix, say, df1, df2 and df3. Remaining columns can be dropped from combined df.

If I do the following:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
df_f = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)
df_f = df_f.loc[:,~df_f.columns.duplicated()]
```

This will remove all duplicated columns and will be *left with one set of columns (for df1).*

So one way to prevent the unwanted deletion of column could be r*enaming the selected columns* as indicated above.

How can I achieve the same. I want programmatically adding suffix to those selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can `rename` columns from list in list comprehension with `enumerate` for counter:

```
cols = ["Short Rule Name", "Incident", "Rule_No", "Flag_Type"]
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [df.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols, [f'{x}_{i}' for x in cols]))) 
       for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1)]

df_f = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)
df_f = df_f.loc[:,~df_f.columns.duplicated()]
```

Sample for first part:

```
cols = ["Short Rule Name", "Incident", "Rule_No", "Flag_Type"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols + ['a', 'b'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols + ['a', 'c'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols + ['b', 'c'])
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

dfs = [df.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols, [f'{x}_{i}' for x in cols]))) 
       for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1)]

print (dfs)
[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Short Rule Name_1, Incident_1, Rule_No_1, Flag_Type_1]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Short Rule Name_2, Incident_2, Rule_No_2, Flag_Type_2, a, b]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Short Rule Name_3, Incident_3, Rule_No_3, Flag_Type_3, a, c]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Short Rule Name_4, Incident_4, Rule_No_4, Flag_Type_4, b, c]
Index: []]
```

Comment: Hello Sir,Hope you are doing well..It would be really helpful for me if you undelete your answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67872044/show-the-first-string-from-a-list-of-strings-that-appears-in-a-column-of-strings/67872097#67872097

Comment: @AnuragDabas - I think regex should be slow, so it was reason why removed.

Comment: but sir that was indeed a good method as compared to `str.findall()` If possible then can you pls undelete for 2-3 minutes as it was really helpful for me to learn new things **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas - sure, it is somenthing else.

Comment: @jezrael: What if I have 4 dfs and 3 columns...will `zip()` work?

Comment: @pythondumb - added sample data for see `4 dfs and 3 column`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column with the content of the old one and a new label like:

```
df1["Short Rule Name df1"] = df1["Short Rule Name"]
```

Then drop the old column using drop()

And to do it programmatically, you can pop it in a for loop

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
i=1
for df in dfs:
    df["Short Rule Name df" + str(i)] = df["Short Rule Name"]
    df.drop("Short Rule Name", axis=1, inplace=True)
    i+=1
```